# Failed in index document with array of hashes in elasticsearch 2.3 by ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby, elasticsearch, hash, rubygems

I would like to added in elasticsearch 2.3 document with array of hashes with help with ruby.
I use gem elasticsearch (1.0.6). In elasticsearch 1.7 this code is working, in elasticsearch 2.3 this code in not working.

```
require 'elasticsearch'
doc = []
doc.push({'test' => 'test'})
client = Elasticsearch::Client.new(host:'localhost')
client.index index:'test', type:'test', id:'1', body:{doc: doc}
```

Comment: Please post the error you get

Comment: Error was in incorrect mapping. Problem solved.